# How do I extract a date from a text file containing extraneous characters?

Tags: python, string, data-cleaning

`List1` below was created using an OCR process on an image using Python 2.7.

```
List1 = ["ERNR'W\xe2\x80\x98IWW/ftfi M '* \xe2\x80\x98\r\n", '\xe2\x80\x98 L n 4\r\n', 'May 2001\r\n', '31 Thursday ,_,,\r\n', '(161-214)\r\n', '0700\r\n']
```

It includes information that I wish to filter out, specifically the date information i.e. `Thursday 31 May 2001`.

I tried splitting the items in the list to get this list:

```
["'*", '(161-214)', ',_,,', '0700', '2001', '31', '4', 'L', 'M', 'May', 'Thursday', 'n']
```

I have no trouble filtering out the year, the month or the day of the week so I can achieve `Thursday May 2001`. 
However, I cannot figure out a way to filter the day of the month - in this example, to distinguish between the extraneous '4' and the required '31'.

The day of the month (here, 31) always appears adjacent to the day of the week. 
Is there a way I could use this fact to extract the '31'?

So, in short, how can I get `Thursday 31 May 2001` (in any order) from `List1`?

Answer (score 0):

You could look for a number followed by a weekday with a regex:

```
import re

List1 = ["ERNR'W\xe2\x80\x98IWW/ftfi M '* \xe2\x80\x98\r\n", '\xe2\x80\x98 L n 4\r\n', 'May 2001\r\n', '31 Thursday ,_,,\r\n', '(161-214)\r\n', '0700\r\n']
day_and_weekday = re.compile('(\d+) ((mon|tue|wednes|thurs|fri|satur|sun)day)', re.I)

for text in List1:
  match = day_and_weekday.match(text)
  if match:
    print('Day : %s' % match.group(1))
    print('Weekday : %s' % match.group(2))
```

It outputs:

```
Day : 31
Weekday : Thursday
```

Comment: Eric Duminil. That was fast and is very helpful. I can use this to get what I want.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use regex, here is another solution.

```
List1 = ["ERNR'W\xe2\x80\x98IWW/ftfi M '* \xe2\x80\x98\r\n", '\xe2\x80\x98 L n 4\r\n', 'May 2001\r\n', '31 Thursday ,_,,\r\n', '(161-214)\r\n', '0700\r\n']

days = ['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday']

for string in List1:
    for day in days:
        index = string.lower().find(day)
        if  index != -1:
            dayNum = string[:index]

print('Day: ' + dayNum)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for providing quality answer.